# Secret Hidden message on keyboard enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just had a thought and was wondering if it was possible in the spirit of april fools.

Is it possible to have a secret code that you randomly type in a website similar to that on a gaming console like (a, up, down, b, L1, R1), but on the website, you would type on your keyboard "9 2 k (uparrow) 3" and as long as you're on the website, it does something, let's say `alert('hey')`?  Curious to see how you would do it.

Comment: **Yes**, that is possible, for that you've to write code. First bind keypress event on document, catch them get keyCode somewhere. When they come in sequence within short duration(_say 1 second_) execute `alert('hey fool!')`

Comment: You could even send the characters through a websocket and check them on the server, if you don't want users to be able to inspect the source of the website and figure out the combination. (and if you don't mind the bandwidth).

Comment: @JCOC611 While that's a cool idea in theory, it's rare for even analytic services to feel that invasive, since that essentially could make the website look like a keylogger.

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi it's not really that bad, since it would only log keys if you have the site focused. If you switch tabs to your bank, the keys won't be logged.

Comment: @JCOC611 Maybe I'm an outlier, but it'd give me the heebie jeebies. Paritcularly if the site's interaction-heavy. But that's up to the site owner and their users :^)

Answer (score 4):

```
  // our combo
  var combo = [57, 50, 75, 38, 51];

  var keys = new Array(combo.length);
  $(document).on('keydown', function(evt){
    // remove the earliest of the stored keys
    keys.shift();
    // push in the latest key pressed
    keys.push(evt.which);

    // compare with combo array - you could use any comparison method (convert to string,...)
    if (!keys.some(function(e, i) { return e !== combo[i] }))
      alert('hey')
  })
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kzj5e7Lk/

You'll need to click in the run area (bottom right pane) before you try the key combination.

Comment: Won't this shift off the first keys of the combo before you can input the whole thing? If you iterate over `keys`, won't the alert fire as soon as you put in the first key of the combo?

Comment: you're only pushing 1 code into the keys array on each keypress (while also popping off the oldest unrequired key - notice that the keys array is initialized to be as long as the combo). Then you basically compare the last x (=combo length) keys against the combo and alert if it matches. Cheers!

Comment: Ah you init with a length, I missed that part so it looked like you would push and then immediately shift off the same key!

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's a few things you could do to capitalize on this, and make it more obfuscated so the user has to jump through some more hoops to get the secret key combination, but this should be good enough for a basic implementation.

```js
var code = '.57.50.75.38.51';
var entered = '';
var clearCombo;

//keypress won't register up arrow

$('body').keydown(function (e) {
  clearTimeout(clearCombo);
  entered += '.' + e.which;
  clearCombo = setTimeout(function () {
    entered = '';
  }, 1000);
  if (entered === code) {
    alert('i pity the foobar');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That'll require them to enter the code with each character within one second of each other. (`set`/`clearTimeout`) It also means they'll have to wait for the timeout to clear out their entered keys if they mess up.

You might also want to check out [Mousetrap](https://craig.is/killing/mice) if you don't mind including an additional library.

Comment: Upvoted but I think an array is more elegant than a string with separators.

Comment: I was tempted to make that exact comment on potatopeelings' answer. It's more concise, and clean. The only boon with the string concatenation is that it's a simple `===` comparison, rather than looping through each element. Though it could be the same with the array, using `.join()`. Really any benefit from this method are nominal at best, and nonexistent at worst. :)